# Docker container tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter provides 0 kernels

Tags: docker, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run the official Tensorflow docker image **tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter** on my 64bit Ubuntu machine. A supported GPU is present an works with Python/Tensorflow in a non-dockerized environment. However, when starting the container via:

```
docker run --gpus all -it --rm tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter
```

There is no kernel present (when shutting down, the message "Shutting down 0 kernels" pops up). When connecting for instance with VSCode to the Notebook, no code can be run. I didn't find anything regarding that problem on the net. Any pitfalls I might have went into while installing the container?

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me if this is obvious, but docker containers have their own ip address/ports. If you are running this container (I do) you have to map its port 8888 to your local port. So the minimum docker command is:
*run --gpus all -it --rm -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter*
(on one line). In your browser then open localhost:8888. Get the token from the terminal log from the docker command. you can then test whether tensorflow is running and using the gpu. You can do this in a notebook, or just by running one of the examples in the container (/tf) and looking at the server log. To connect to vscode you'll need some more port forwarding.